# Is a service the right way to manage a socket connection in an application?

Tags: android, sockets, android-service

When having an application that needs a connection with a server all the time, no matter what activity is showing the socket connection should be persistent, does a local bound service fulfill this job? Add 2 methods to the service maybe, ( readString(), sendOutput() ) to manage incoming and outgoing messages through the connected socket. Bound to service when needed on each activity making sure that the service is always running. 
Would that work ? is there another better approach for achieving a persistent socket connection through the app ?

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable to me! The only thing I wouldn't be sure about is about a 'permanent socket', nowadays it's more common to have periodic requests to optimize battery and network resources.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain more what do you mean by having a periodic  request? if you need the connection to always be alive, you cant do that right ?

Comment: periodic requests, like http requests. For example if your app is a newspaper, you could connect every 5 minutes to download the latest news, you wouldn't need a permanent connection. But it is just an example

Comment: ohh got it. well my app is a chatting app so i dont guess i can use that approach